# download file from FileNet IDM using IDM objects

Tags: c#-4.0, filenet-panagon, filenet-idm

i have code to download file from FileNet IDM server. using IDM docid but i want to pass property field and download it. what idmobjects should i use it.?

please help on this. am new to IDM.

```
        fnObjectType = IDMObjects.idmObjectType.idmObjTypeDocument;           

        int pagec = 0;
        try
        {
            fnGenericObj = fnLibrary.GetObject(fnObjectType, argDocid,
                                     objMissing, objMissing, objMissing);
            fnDoc = (IDMObjects.Document)fnGenericObj;
            pagec = fnDoc.PageCount;
        }
```

Comment: A FileNet "document" has "content" (for example, a TIFF image stored in a library) and "properties" (for example, "name" or "claim #").  You can retrieve a document using docId.  You can also "search" for documents matching some property.  Once you have a docId, you can download the content.  Q: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i want to find docid from property search.

Comment: dont have IDM documentation. if there please share link. thanks for the help.

Comment: It sounds like you need to write a "search" query.  You can find the IDM documentation and sample code here: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27009996.  Note that the documentation and examples pretty much assume VB6.  You can certainly use C#, but you'll need to translate.

Comment: Thank you so much. i will look into the documentation.